# Dividing double-precision shell variables in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, double, division

I am working with shell scripting on Linux.

I have 2 double variables and i want to divide them, and put the results into another variable.

I tried the following (does not work) :

```
#!/bin/bash
A=333.33
B=111.11
C="$A / $B" | bc -l
```

although the following does work:

```
#!/bin/bash
A=333.33
B=111.11
echo "$A / $B" | bc -l
```

what am i doing wrong?

Thanks
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipes work on output streams, and:

```
C="$A / $B" | bc -l
```

does not send `"$A / $B"` to the output stream, instead just sends an eof.

You can do this:

```
C=$(echo "$A / $B" | bc -l)
```

to get the result into `C`.

Answer (score 0):

"$A / $B" is just a string so piping (|) it to "bc -l" doesn't work. A pipe "connects" stdout from one process with stdin on another. echo "$A / $B" on the other hand passes the value of the string to stdout and the pipe passes it to stdin of bc, which works as expected.

Comment: If you want the result in variable C: C=`echo "$A / $B" | bc -l`

Comment: should say C=backtick echo ... backtick

Answer (score 0):

When you use a pipe, you must to push an output :

```
commandA|commandB
```

The `commandA` output is pushed in the pipeline and processed by `commandB`. So `commandA` must print an output in the `stdout` stream which is processed by the pipe.

So you could use instead :

```
C=$(echo "$A / $B"|bc -l)
# or
C=`echo "$A / $B"|bc -l`
# or
C=$(bc -l <<< "$A / $B")
# or 
C=`bc -l <<< "$A / $B"`
```

If you want to set the result into a variable.

Answer (score 0):

That's the working version:

```
#!/bin/bash
A=333.33
B=111.11
C=`bc -l <<< "$A/$B"`
echo $C
```